# Accessing private attributes across files - Understanding the Error, Python 3.8.2

Tags: python

I have 2 files, first.py and second.py, while trying to acces a private attribute of *second* from *first*, I encountered an odd Traceback

These are the code snippets:

first:

```
from second import B
class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        ob = B()
        self.a = 6
        self.b = ob.__b

aObj = A()
```

second.py:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__b = 10
```

The Traceback I am getting:

```
     self.b = ob.__b
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_A__b'
```

I know it is not possible to access a private variable across files without getters and setters, I am just trying to understand where the error I am getting come from.

Where does the _A__b come from? I am curious as I tried to access ob.__b and not ob._A__b , what does _A try to signify? because if I remove the '__' prefix, and write this instead:

```
self.b = ob.b
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Without _A before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to clean up some confusion: python permits access to any and all private and public variables - it does not enforce them at all. Some language (Java, C#), do others do not.
"_" and "__" are merely conventions, and if you access them the risk is on you.

You just have to know how they are called.

"__" Invokes name mangling though, e.g. the name are modified to prevent accidental naming clashes. This is explained here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/name-mangling-in-python/

For your example, you need to access it like this:

```
from second import B
class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        ob = B()
        self.a = 6
        self.b = ob._B__b

aObj = A()
```

Further warning: Files (called modules in python parlance) have nothing to do with your problems, you can easily have A and B in the same file. Again, some language enforce or at least encourage a class per file (Java, C#) - but python does not. You do not need classes at all in a module.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment! so basically _B represents the class-name, thank you again.